# What is the best way to serialize user elements in epub (html) reader apps (android sdk, ios,web etc)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web, epub

We are developing epub reader library. 
Our users will be able to synchronize their reading (through the server api)  on any devices (web browser, android sdk app, ios app etc).
And we should support synchronization of user notes, quotations, read positions,  bookmarks. We support text size changing also. And we use css columns for book paggination.

Now for serialization we are trying to use  timdown/rangy library (TextRange module): https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module to determine text positions relative to book chapter (html body).

But we note:

- js functions like selectCharacters(Node containerNode, Number startIndex, Number endIndex) works very slowly
- text-position mismatch after text size changing

We are thinking about using the same rangy functions but relative to nearest dom element (p). But in this case we'll have to identify dom elements each time in some universal for all clients way.

What is the best way to serialize - deserialize user elements in our case ?

Of course,  it's our work and so our problems, but we'll be very grateful for your any advice !

Answer (score 1):

The one and only "IDPF-blessed" way to keep track of the current reading position consists in storing the EPUB CFI (see http://www.idpf.org/epub/linking/cfi/epub-cfi.html ) of the first visible element in the current viewport.

Similarly for highlights, annotations, bookmarks.

Note that if you manipulate the DOM of the original EPUB asset (say, XHTML file) before passing it to your renderer (say, a WebView), then you should keep track of the map between the original and the modified DOM, in order to apply CFIs consistently.

The Readium JS project has a Javascript module for dealing with CFIs that you might find useful: https://github.com/readium/readium-cfi-js